# Solidity | Proper use of "using a for b" statement in derived contracts

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, openzeppelin

I have a contract using Open-Zeppelin SafeMath, but that declaration is not recognized by derived contracts.

**Base.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Base  {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
}
```

**Test.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.4;

import "Base.sol";

contract Test is Base {
    function getnum(uint256 _number) external view returns (uint256) {
        return _number.add(_number);
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Member "add" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256.
```

Answer (score 0):

`using A for B` statemen has changed in solidity 0.7, now we have to repeat the statement in all derived contracts:

> `using A for B` only affects the contract it is mentioned in.
> Previously, the effect was inherited. Now, you have to repeat the
> `using` statement in all derived contracts that make use of the feature.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.4/070-breaking-changes.html#functions-and-events